Are my plans feasible?
Have an area I want to add some deck'g 2 in order to expand the space of a concrete porch. Fr. wall of house outward I'm going 12'by 6'. R 2-2x12x12 enuf? to support 1x6x6 planking. The 2x12x12s will rest on 4 4x4x 11.25.  The posts will be placed into four deck blocks at each corner and the 2- 2x12x12s will rest on the posts on the 1.5" edges

I think newer decks need 6x6 posts.  Your local building department will be the best place to ask, since they will give the permits/have the local regulations.

Your climate will also be needed to see if deck blocks are enough or if you need to dig below the frost line.  With 11.25 posts, I doubt if deck blocks are enough.
